# Direct image of an ideal sheaf along a blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $I\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ is a saturated homogeneous ideal. Let $\mathcal{I}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ denote the corresponding coherent ideal sheaf, and then let $$\pi:Y=\mathrm{Bl}_{\mathcal{I}}(\mathbb{P}^n)\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ along $\mathcal{I}$. Since $\mathbb{P}^n$ is normal, we know that $\mathcal{J}=\pi_*(\mathcal{I}\cdot\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a coherent ideal sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$. In general, $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ are not the same, so my question is:

Given $I$, how can I compute the saturated homogeneous ideal $$J=\bigoplus_{d\geq 0}\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{J}(d))\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$$ (which, of course, is just the graded ideal attached to $\mathcal{J}$)? Is there a way to do it efficiently? By 'efficiently' I mean using a computer program like Macaulay2.

Note that if we took the normalised blow-up, $J$ would simply be the integral closure of $I$.